# OpenX ads hacked

Tags: ads, openx

We use OpenX for serving ads on our websites.

Received a complaint (with a screenshot) from one of our clients - "Why do I get the ad on your homepage linking to an adult site?". Everything seems fine on the server side and none of us could replicate the problem on the server. Looks like it is a client side issue. Is it some type of a malware that hacks Flash plug-ins?

Any idea what could cause all the ads on our pages to be replaced with ads we never served? Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else, who runs into this issue.... Looks like the client had some spyware on his machine, that caused all ads to be hijacked.

Answer (score 3):

OpenX 2.8 has known exploit from SQL injection. Upgrade your version or switch to a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The client could be using a rogue DNS... Either the DNS server on his machine has been changed or his router has been hacked.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That doesn't seem to be the issue. Since he can get to the same IP for other resources without any issues. This seems to affect ads only.